# Question regarding UIButton

Tags: iphone

everyone

I have 1 UIButton with 1 image with blue colour
but when i click on UIButton at that time i want  to remove that image and add 1 another image.

Answer (score 0):

In code you can set button image following way:

```
[yourButton setImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]; // or for whatever state you want
```

You can also set all necessary images in IB for all possible states (default, highlighted and selected)

Comment: It's not happens when i click 1 st time 
it's happens 2 nd time and afterwards

Comment: Where do you set an image to your button? If you just have 1 image for each state - better set them in IB (or on view controller's initialization)